# Get value from another table without common key on which to join

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I have two tables in a Postgres 9.6 DB, `person` and `grade`:

Person:

| id | name | score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | apple | 8 |
| 4 | berry | 9 |
| 6 | cat | 5 |
| 7 | dog | 2 |

Grade:

| grade | min_score | max_score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| D | 0 | 2 |
| C | 3 | 5 |
| B | 6 | 8 |
| A | 9 | 10 |

DDL & DML:

```
create table Person (ID int, name varchar, score int);
create table Grade (grade varchar, min_score int, max_score int);

insert into Person values
 (1, 'apple', 8), (4, 'berry', 9), (6, 'cat', 5), (7, 'dog', 2);
insert into Grade values
 ('D', 0, 2), ('C', 3, 5), ('B', 6, 8), ('A', 9, 10);
```

I want to construct a query without `CASE` or `JOIN` (cannot join, no common key) to list `name` and `grade`.
This query does not work:

```
select * from Grade g
where (select score from Person) between g.min_score and g.max_score;
```

Ideal output would be:

| name | grade |
| --- | --- |
| apple | B |
| berry | A |
| cat | C |
| dog | D |

Comment: Aside: Postgres 9.6 has reached EOL in 2021. Consider upgrading to a current version. See: https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need a "common key" for a join. Any Boolean expression works as join condition:

```sql
SELECT p.name, g.grade
FROM   person p
JOIN   grade  g ON p.score BETWEEN g.min_score AND g.max_score;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/V7HgFg6_)

More in [the manual on joining tables](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-JOIN).

Comment: Confirmed. Didn't know boolean expression works..Thanks